# Removing Label if Exist in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added labels programmatically and now i want to edit the text of these labels. But the problem is  every time new label is created when I press `Done` Button and If I apply `if-condition` then the label removes when clicked on `Back` Button.

Here is my code:

```
-(void) LaunchText:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{

n=[SingleTon getInstance];
UIView *theView = sender.view;
n.passingText=(UILabel*)theView;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"textAdd" sender:self];

if(![theView isDescendantOfView:self.view])

{   //myView is not subview of self.view, add it.

          [self.view addSubview:theView];

}

   else{

            [theView removeFromSuperview];

}

}


CGRect rect = CGRectMake(35, 60,takenText.contentSize.width,takenText.contentSize.height);

UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

rect.origin.x=0;
rect.origin.y=0;
UILabel *textLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];


[textLabel setText:takenText.text];
 //self.text=takenText.text;
[textLabel setTextColor:takenText.textColor];
[textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:takenText.font.fontName size:takenText.font.pointSize]];
[textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[textLabel sizeToFit];
[holderView setTag:1];
[textLabel setTag:1+1];
[textLabel removeFromSuperview];
[holderView addSubview:textLabel];

 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LaunchText:)];

[doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[doubleTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];


[textLabel addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
textLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

I am doing this all on `unwind seque` .

Comment: I'm confused. Which label are you trying to edit, and which are you trying to remove? Is the label the view with the GestureRecognizer that calls the method?

Comment: yes Gesture recognizer calls the method `LaunchText` and then it gets the text of label on which i tapped

Comment: And what is the problem? The label is always removed? I don't really understand your first post. What is it that you are trying to do? It seems like whatever it is you probably aren't going about it in the easiest way.

Comment: I am trying to check if the label exist then delete it and if not then add new. this is working perfectly but when i double tap on it and press the Back button if i don't want to edit it then there is no label because it has been already deleted. i am asking what to do when click on Done button this condition apply else the label should not delete