# Updating same label with new text in ios

Tags: ios

I am trying to update label. When I tap on label the text is move to textview then when i click on `Done` every time new label is created with updated text. What should I do to update same label? I am using `singleton' for doing so.

Comment: You should post your code so people can help you.

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601832/removing-label-if-exist-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment41819148_26601832

Answer (score 0):

Try searching about IBOutlets and properties of particular UI Elements. Like, you want to change your **.text** property of the UILabel in this case. There is absolutely no use for singletons here.

Comment: I am using singleton because i am passing data from one view controller to another.. and i found singleton useful+ easy for doing so.

Comment: But not the best approach. Use navigation controller, push-pop and create objects. It should help. I'm actually not understanding what you're trying to achieve. Only if you could be more specific.

Comment: I did it using singleton :) i declared the bool variable in singleton class and used it throughout.

Comment: Great! But you may try a more appreciable and easy approach next time. Trust me, outlets are easy too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use viewWithTag to get the existing label if you don't have the instance of label.

For example:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 200, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, CGRectGetWidth(myView.frame), 50)];
[myLabel setTag:1001]; // We can use this tag to find the label from different place.
[myView addSubview:myLabel];
```

To find the label

```
UILabel *mLabel = (UILabel *) [myView viewWithTag:1001];
if (mLabel) {
    [mLabel setText:@"Hello"];
}
```